# change css attribute if font is over given size

Tags: css

I would like an easy way that could target all fonts sizes below 18px to apply a lower `font-weight` value.

Is this currently possible on CSS?

Comment: You would need to use jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't mentioned about inline styles or css styles, here is one solution. Not elegant though.. :) For inline style (Even though it is not a standard way to use inline styles)

http://jsfiddle.net/J3x4j/

### Html

```
<p style="font-size:11px;">11</p>
<p style="font-size:12px;">12</p>
<p style="font-size:13px;">13</p>
<p style="font-size:14px;">14</p>
<p style="font-size:15px;">15</p>
<p style="font-size:16px;">16</p>
```

### Css

```
[style*=font-size\:11px],[style*=font-size\:12px],[style*=font-size\:13px],[style*=font-size\:14px],[style*=font-size\:15px]
{
    color: blue;
    font-weight:normal !important;
}
p
{
font-weight:bold;
}
```

For css styles you have to go with jquery or javascript as far as i know with css you can quantify or apply numerical expressions.
http://jsfiddle.net/J3x4j/11/

```
$('p').each(function(){
    //replace px or em or whatever unit
    var fontsize = parseInt($(this).css('font-size').replace('px'));
    if(fontsize < 18)
    {
        $(this).css('font-weight','normal');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So basically, you want all text under 18px to be not bold? Basically, all text over 18px is bold. The simplest way (most understandable) would be to just make different classes. For example:

```
.twentypnt{
font-size:20px;
font-weight:bold;
}

.twelvepnt{
font-size:12px;
}
```

Alternately, you could make a javascript statement.

```
function checkWeight(){
if(parseInt(document.getElementById('thing').style.fontsize) > 18)
document.getElementById('thing').style.fontweight = "bold";
}
```

I think that'd work, but then you'd have to run that for each set of text.